# Bootstrap 4 BG video to full screen Modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap 4 site being built, I have a fullscreen BG video on landing page with a "play" button. I would like the modal to be FULLSCREEN when user clicks play. Right now it is very small when the modal opens. I tried using bs-modal-fullscreen plugin but did not seem to fix the issue. Any Advice or anyone know a solution??? Thanks!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="vid p-5">
  <div class="video-container h-100">
    <video class="bg-video" autoplay muted loop>
              <source src="video/people.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser is not supported
            </video>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center text-center text-white">
    <div class="col m-4">
      <h1 class="display-4 banner-heading">
        "We Believe People Make The Difference"
      </h1>
      <p class="lead banner-par">Since 2004</p>
      <a href="#" class="launch-modal" data-modal-id="modal-video">
        <span class="video-link-icon"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-video" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-video-label">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-video">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="video/people.mp4" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , you should write fullscrenn style code. Then, you shoud write js code for click event and add modal-dialog new class. You can examine example

```
.fullscreen{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addClass(){
        document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.add('fullscreen');
    }
</script>
...
<button onclick="addClass()">ClickEvent/button>
```